# Animation angular only working in false state

Tags: css, angular

I have one animation in angular fadein/fadeout, this work normally before i upgrade angular v6 to v7. My code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss', 
  ],
  animations: [
   trigger('hideShowAnimator', [
    state('true', style({ opacity: 1, display: 'block' })),
    state('false', style({ opacity: 0, display: 'none' })),
    transition('0 => 1', animate('200ms ease-in')),
    transition('1 => 0', animate('200ms ease-out'))
  ])
  ],

})
```

So, i apply in my div:

```
    <div [@hideShowAnimator]="abreNotificacoes" id="cardNotificacao" class="card">


   ...

<i (click)="abreNotificacoes = !abreNotificacoes"></i>
```

Now, only my fadeOut is working. why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the visibility property instead, and if you want to get rid of the space occupied by container then set the height property to 0 and vice versa.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('hideShowAnimator', [
      state('true', style({ opacity: 1, visibility: 'visible' })),
      state('false', style({ opacity: 0, visibility: 'hidden' })),
      transition('0 => 1', animate('500ms ease-in')),
      transition('1 => 0', animate('500ms ease-out')),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

I noticed this is happening because the position (x, y) of the box and button changes. The following works if they are both side by side:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
  <ul>
    <i (click)="toggle()">Click</i>
  </ul>
  <div [@hideShowAnimator]="abreNotificacoes" id="cardNotificacao" class="card">
    <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i use visibility: hidden, my element hidden but the space of the element persist in my screen. this is why i need to display: none, how i can fix this?

Comment: @hiLorena Set the height property to 0. and when visible, set back to the height you want.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `display: 'none'`. If you change that to `block` it works as expected but having it to `none` means it won't be displayed until after the transition because css style with `opacity: X, display: 'none'` where `X` is any value will still never render.

```
animations: [
  trigger('hideShowAnimator', [
  state('true', style({ opacity: 1, display: 'block' })),
  state('false', style({ opacity: 0, display: 'block' })),
  transition('0 => 1', animate('200ms ease-in')),
  transition('1 => 0', animate('200ms ease-out'))
])],
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpgjzx)

Comment: if i use visibility: hidden, my element hidden but the space of the element persist in my screen. this is why i need to display: none, how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think display:none could be the problem. Its better to use *ngIf provied by angular.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss', 
  ],
  animations: [
  trigger('hideShowAnimator', [
    transition('void => *', [
      style({opacity:0}),
      animate(200ms ease-in, style({opacity:1})) 
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(200ms ease-in, style({opacity:0})) 
    ])
  ])
})
```

```
  <div [@hideShowAnimator] id="cardNotificacao" class="card" *ngIf="abreNotificacoes">


   ...

<i (click)="abreNotificacoes = !abreNotificacoes"></i>
```

Comment: if i use *ngIf with the animation the ngif instantly hide my element

Comment: Did you import the BrowserAnimationsModule in your app.module?